# Problems accessing my Ubuntu system

Tags: command-line, updates, graphics, remote-access, environment

I have a problem accessing to my Ubuntu 13.04 system. Recently I updated from 12 to 13 and after some hard work I am able to input my password and user name, but I can't get any further, because the system doesn't recognize my password and/or account. So I have no access to the graphic environment, only to a terminal. Some people told me that may be it's a resolution problem. Can somebody tell me what's wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Are you using 13.04 or 13.10 because 13.10 isn't supported anymore.

Comment: Can you paste part of your `/var/log/syslog` to paste.ubuntu.com after you fail access GUI.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

and then in the terminal enter:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

and then you chose lightdm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a new account and chek if you can login:

```
sudo useradd -m username

sudo passwd username
```

Try also what [Michael](https://askubuntu.com/users/256628/michael) said:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Followed by the last command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Comment: I did what Michael said, but it doesn't work. And so I try your recommendation and now I can get in on my graphical environment, but now the problem is that I don't have acces to my super user account because the system still doesn't whant my password. What should I do? Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have acces to sudo user, it was a lenguage configuration keyboard problem. Thank you. One more question, do you recommend to update my system to the 14.04 version?

Comment: Yes I suggest you to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with 16.04. The cause was my graphic adapter driver (newer versions of Xorg, Lightdm or whatever after update/upgrade conflicted with it). Reinstalling/updating Nautilus, Xorg etc. didn't help but complete uninstall of graphic driver did the job. In my case it was Nvidia so I typed to the command line `sudo apt-get purge Nvidia*`, then restarted. Of course it started with crapy resolution and required to reinstall the driver but it worked and works so far.
So the sequence that worked for me was:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install lightdm`
`sudo apt-get install gdm` (then choosed lightdm)
`sudo apt-get purge Nvidia*`
`sudo reboot`
The "password loop" disappeared and then I just installed again my Nvidia driver to restore acceptable screen resolution.