# no launchers after update ubuntu 16.04

Tags: launcher

after an update the top panel  showing the time and the launchers on the left side don't appear. Otherwise the desktop is as it used to be with all the windows. If I log in with my guest account everything works well, it's just the main account. I tried a couple if things that Ifound here in the forum, but nothing really worked. I would appreciate an easy solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem after updating to 16.04, also (already with 16.04) I had "password loop" problem on startup, it's widely discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474062/problems-accessing-my-ubuntu-system). In both cases the cause was my graphic adapter driver (newer versions of Xorg, Lightdm or whatever after update/upgrade conflicted with it).
Reinstalling/updating Nautilus, Xorg etc. didn't help but complete uninstall of graphic driver did the job. In my case it was Nvidia so I typed to the command line `sudo apt-get purge Nvidia*`, then restarted. Of course it started with crapy resolution and required to reinstall the driver but it worked and works so far.